# Performing a complex query with firestore v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm attempting to perform a complex query with firestore v9. My intention is to get some docs (skip and limit) from a my data structure. What I mean is, I need to get for example 5 docs from a doc -> collections -> doc. and this docs need to be order by there date.

[image]
[image]

So for example, lets say in my array I contain 2 docs id `['e4z3HNyUCQbiYQRzfVO4RyebMCP2', 'WZImI6tl0IUFKbICEZzcciaUxKG2']`, from this 2 docs, I would need to get their userPosts ordered by the creation date, but I would need to pass a skip and limit too. So from this 2 docs, I would limit 3 docs to get, but these 3 docs will be from the 2 posts ids I passed.

[image]

```
 const queryBuild = await query(
    collection(db, 'posts'),
    where('userPosts', 'in', [`post.id`...]),
    collection(db, 'userPosts'),
    ...
  );
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryBuild);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do what you are looking for with Firestore.

You will need to issue two queries, one for each of the two parent document.

---

Let say, for example, that in total you only want 3 documents from the two sub-collections.

You first query the first subcollection with the following query:

```
const q1 = query(collection(db, "posts/e4z3HNyUCQbiYQRzfVO4RyebMCP2/userPosts"), orderBy("creation", "desc"), limit(3));
```

You then query the second subcollection with the following query:

```
const q2 = query(collection(db, "posts/WZImI6tl0IUFKbICEZzcciaUxKG2/userPosts"), orderBy("creation", "desc"), limit(3));
```

Then you merge the two results (i.e. push the documents of the two `QuerySnapshot`s in one Array), order them by descending `creation` value and take the first three ones.

Comment: so for example, if the user has a 1000 posts, I would need to fetch all of them?

Comment: No, since you only want (for example) 3 documents in total you can query, for each subcollection, the 3 most recent documents. I forgot to mention that in my answer, I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Renaud's answer would be to store the `postId` of the parent document in each `userPost`. With that you could add an [`in` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) to a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to get the user posts of up to 10 parent documents.

```
query(
  collectionGroup(db, "userPosts"), 
  orderBy("creation", "desc"), 
  where("parentPostId", "in", ["e4z3HNyUCQbiYQRzfVO4RyebMCP2", "WZImI6tl0IUFKbICEZzcciaUxKG2"]), 
  limit(3)
);
```

If you have more than 10 IDs, you'll need to perform multiple of such queries, so you'd be back to a similar approach as in Renaud answers, just with 1/10th as many API calls.